# Duplicate ethernet cables for redundancy?

Tags: ethernet, redundancy

Between 2 standard Ethernet switches I want to run 2 Ethernet cables to give some redundancy should one of the cables fail:

Will this setup cause any network issues?

Will I need to use managed switches for this to work?

Comment: You will need to use switches that support spanning tree. If you have multiple VLANs and some of them might have loops, it can get more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this setup only if the switches support it.

On a blank cheap 8-port switch you will cause a network loop.

On a better switch like a Zyxel, you will be able to configure the equivalent of CISCO's etherchannel, meaning you will have 2 wires combined working at double the speed and if one of them fails there will be no disconnection, the connection will continue to function correctly on the remaining one.